# Is Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5 compatible with Java EE 5?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty

It's not entirely clear to me if Liberty Profile 8.5.5 support Java EE 5. On the official compatibility page for EE 6 Liberty Profile is explicitly listed:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html

However on the EE 5 compatibility page only Websphere is listed:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-javaee5-jsp-141098.html

Can I assume that if an implementation supports EE 6 then it also supports all previous EE versions?

Does anyone have a source clearly stating that Liberty Profile is EE 5 compatible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java EE 5 compatibility list shows only servers implementing *full profile*. WebSphere Liberty currently implements *web profile*, so cant be listed there.

*Can I assume that if an implementation supports EE 6 then it also supports all previous EE versions?*

No, for example Liberty doesn't support EJB 2.x, which is required by Java EE 1.4. Only full WebSphere Application Server is backward compatible with all previous specs. In general, it depends from application server vendor, they usually support some previous versions, but you cannot assume that, if server supports Java EE 6, it will support all previous specs. This definitely is not true.

*Does anyone have a source clearly stating that Liberty Profile is EE 5 compatible?*

As Liberty doesn't implement full profile, you cannot say it is fully EE 5 compatible, however you will be able to run some Java EE 5 web applications on it, where the spec is backward compatible. Here is list of [features supported by Liberty](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F2-0-2-2-0&lang=en). So for example you can run Servlet 2.5 apps, but you cannot use *remote* EJB 3.0.

**Update**

WebSphere Liberty profile starting with 8.5.5.6 version is now **fully Java EE 7 compliant**.

Comment: Where do you see that Liberty supports Servlet 2.5 apps? I can only see a reference to Servlet 3.0. Does that imply 2.5 support?

Comment: @kutuzof I just created sample Java EE 5 app, with servlet and web.xml v2.5 and it runs fine.

Comment: @kutuzof Also check this - [Java EE FAQ - compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaee-faq-jsp-135209.html#apps) - "Backwards compatibility is a requirement of the specification." So you could assume it would be backward compatible to Java EE 5 *web profile* if it would exist :)